Optimize Brass Ring Game for Carousel
Background: We are a carousel with a brass ring game. Our game uses a cartridge which dispenses 35 rings per ride, and we have it loaded with 33 plastic rings and 2 brass rings loaded 15-16 rings apart. Riders getting a brass ring get a free ride. We have 1 to 13 possible riders in the outside row that can play the game. Each ride is 7.5 revolutions, and we wait until the ride is up to speed before deploying the game, so each rider gets 6-7 chances to grab a ring. We frequently see one member of a family get a brass ring and then go buy more ride tokens so everyone can ride again.  We also frequently see the same rider get both rings.
Challenge: We want to optimize the number of families getting one brass ring and not multiple brass rings.  Increasing the number of brass rings would increase both the chances for families to get a ring and also the chances that a family would get multiple rings.  Placing only one brass ring in the cartridge would ensure no one person or family would get multiple rings and would also limit the chance to win to one family.
The Question: What arrangement of plastic and brass rings will give us the optimal chance for the most families getting one brass ring?

This looks complicated: a person or family getting two brass rings presumably happens because other people have taken the intermediate plastic rings. But it may be complicated by varying sizes of families and varying skill at grabbing a ring.  If you could set up a model appropriately, simulation might give you an answer.

For those who do not understand at first, see here where the concept is explained (it isn't known worldwide ; for example, nothing really equivalent in my country, France)

Do you know what percentage of people pull out a ring at all? Are the people getting multiple brass rings the ones pulling a ring every turn of the carousel?

Alex, each ride differs depending on the number of riders in the outside row and how many are playing.  I can be anywhere from 1 to 13.  If there are only one or two pulling rings, they will be pulling only 12-14 rings and are unlikely to get a brass ring which is usually at position 16. On the other hand, if we don't switch the cartridge or pull it down, refill it, and put it back up, the next set of riders will find a brass ring in position 2-4.  If 5 or more riders are playing, they will empty the cartridge almost every time.

If 4 or 8 riders are playing and the brass rings are spaced every 16 spaces, they are it is likely that the same person will get both rings, although there is some randomness to how we load the rings (not exactly 15 plastic for every brass).
What I  am really looking for is will adding more brass rings (perhaps 10 to 1) increase the probability that several families will get only one ring or decrease it (because the same family gets multiple rings)?

I have not received much response to this post.  Are there other tags that I should include to reach the right audience or other resources outside the Stack Exchange that might be able to help me?
